# Exanding the a summation squared

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, summation

I am reviewing a proof as part of a courser course on regression, but I am getting hung up on some intermediate steps.

The proof we are working is a proof that Y-bar (the average of the individual Y values) is the minimizer for the following formula which is a function of mu:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} (Y_i - \mu)^2
$$

The professor's proof begins as follows:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} (Y_i - \mu)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(Y_i - \overline{Y} + \overline{Y} -  \mu)^2
$$

The next line of the proof is:

$$
= \sum_{i=1}^{n} (Y_i - \overline{Y})^2 + 2\sum_{i=1}^{n} (Y_i - \overline{Y})(\overline{Y} - \mu) + \sum_{i=1}^{n}(\overline{Y} -  \mu)^2
$$

My issue is the steps between those lines. I have tried to foil the squared term in my second line above, but was unable to get to the third line. Perhaps I need to work on my algebra related to summations. If anyone can give me any insight into the steps that are occurring here I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\color{red}{Y_i - \overline{Y}} + \color{blue}{\overline{Y} -  \mu})^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\left[(\color{red}{Y_i-\overline Y})^2+2(\color{red}{Y_i-\overline Y})(\color{blue}{\overline Y-\mu})+(\color{blue}{\overline Y-\mu})^2\right]$$

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems so obvious when you group the components like that. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Group this way: $(Y_i-\bar Y) + (\bar Y - \mu)= a+b$ where $a:=Y_i-\bar Y$ and $b:=\bar Y - \mu$. FOIL gives
$$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2;$$
substitute back and then use rules of summation.

Comment: Thank you for the help!